# Visual Studio 2015 Freezes on Performing Checkout

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

In Visual Studio 2015, when I save I sporadically get the following dialog after saving a file in source control (specifically, I am using TFS 2017).

[image]

This is a modal dialog that blocks any input into the application.

Regardless of whether I let it continue or if I press cancel (as I have done so here), it just hangs there indefinitely.  My only recourse is to force quit visual studio and run it again.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see problems like this, my first fall-back is to create a new workspace and start fresh. Sometimes the metadata gets in some sort of state, so it never hurts to start over with a workspace.

Comment: I will give it a try - but I recently reformatted this workstation and it has definitely happened before - I'll create a new workspace and see if that helps.

Comment: Do you know of any way to introduce some sort of timeout so that if it does get hung up, it won't just site there indefinitely?

Comment: You can also try to clean the caches for your VS client, then new workspace  or remap the exacting workspace.